# center a row using Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to center a row (12 column) in Bootstrap 3 ?
I do not want to use the `offset`

I am using this way but not worked.

```css
    .col-centered{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row" style="max-width: 300px;">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-centered">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button id="ItemForSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        All Items 
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul id="NormalSearch" class="dropdown-menu customize-dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"> Test 1 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Test 2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Test 3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Test 4 </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /btn-group -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there any solution to this? I have not an idea for this work.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What you are doing is not working, because you apply the margin: auto to the full-width column.

Wrap it in a div and center that one. E.g:

```
<div class="i-am-centered">
  <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

.

```
.i-am-centered { margin: auto; max-width: 300px;}
```

http://www.bootply.com/93751

Its a cleaner solution anyway, as it is more expressive and as you usually don't want to mess with the grid.

Comment: i use : <div class="im-centered row"> ...</div>. worked. thank you @hugo der hungrige

Comment: How about doing this without guessing the width of the row?

Answer (score 63):

Why not using the grid system?

The bootstrap grid system consist of 12 columns, so if you use the "Medium" columns it will have a 970px width size.

Then you can divide it to 3 columns (12/3=4) so use 3 divs with "col-md-4" class:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

Each one will have 323px max width size.
Keep the first and the last empty and use the middle one to get your content centerd:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <p>Centered content.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

Comment: @AmelSalibasic This answer is directed to the question, please read the question first.

Comment: Explain the terms and conditions

Answer (score 52):

I know this question was specifically targeted at Bootstrap 3, but in case Bootstrap 4 users stumble upon this question, here is how i centered rows in v4:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
  ...
```

More related to this topic can be found on bootstrap [site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: This should be the answer!

Comment: justify-content-center is what I needed for an issue I was having. THANK YOU!

Comment: @Ali: This should not be the answer because it won't work in BS3. If you're coming here for help you're likely not on BS4.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

You could just use

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"></div>
```

As long as you don't want anything in columns 1 & 3 this is a more elegant solution. The offset "adds" 4 columns in front, leaving you with 4 "spare" after.

PS I realise that the initial question specifies no offsets but at least one previous answer uses a CSS hack that is unnecessary if you use offsets. So for completeness' sake I think this is valid.

Answer (score 10):

you can use grid system without adding empty columns

```
<div class="col-xs-2 center-block" style="float:none"> ... </div>
```

change *col-xs-2* to suit your layout.

check preview: http://jsfiddle.net/rashivkp/h4869dja/

Comment: try it before downvoting

Comment: @smartmouse change ```<div class="col-lg-4" style="float:none;">``` to this ```<div class="col-xs-4 center-block" style="float:none;">```. just try to wrap the centering content with required width only, not more than that. col-lg-4 is much larger, and the content will float to left, inside the div.

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your css:

```
.row-centered {
   text-align:center;
}


.col-centered {
   display:inline-block;
   float:none;
   /* reset the text-align */
   text-align:left;
   /* inline-block space fix */
   margin-right:-4px;
}
```

Then, in your HTML code:

```
    <div class=" row row-centered">
        <div class="col-*-*  col-centered>
           Your content
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: The **.row-centered** class :

Comment: The **.row-centered** class : <br>
 -text-align : center => centers the .col element <br>

The **.col-centered**: <br>
 -display: inline-block => make the div acts like an inline element so the "text-align" property can have effect on it and while you are able to set a width or height (*-block) for it. <br>
 - float: none => the float CSS property remove the element from the normal flow. so, we set it to none. <br>
- the rest is some tricks / bootstrap (counter-)fixes !!! <br>



check here:
http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Comment: this will center all the columns inside the row. Hence, the only one column inside of the row as well.

Answer (score 6):

We can also use col-md-offset like this, it would save us from an extra divs code. So instead of three divs we can do by using only one div:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Centered content</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use text-center class

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3 class="text-center">Here Comes your Text</h3>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

this peace of code can help you

```html
<div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 1!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 2!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 3!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in css define the width of center div and center in a document:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple.  The bootstrap  'center-block' never worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use text-align-center in a row like this

```
<div class="row tac">
    <h1>Centered content</h1>
</div>

<style>
 .tac { text-align: center}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the answer about bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
  ...
```

Caution about full width columns, you could need to use col-auto

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
  ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this peace of code and I have successeful

```
<div class="row  center-block">
<div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 90%;"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" style="top:10px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="top:10px;">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of trying to center div's, just add this to your local css.

```
.col-md-offset-15 {
    margin-left: 12.4999999%;
}

which is roughly  offset-1 and half of offset-1. (8.333% + 4.166%) = 12.4999%
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Please read questions carefully... this title of this one says they don't want to use  `offset`, Glad that it worked for your application though.